How to properly resize a window in winapi
I'm trying to do a window resizing like with the WS_OVERLAPPED style using WS_POPUP. Everything worked out on the right side, but there are problems on the left. I can't understand why when I pull the left edge of the window, the mouse cursor is further away than the edge of the window I'm pulling. At the same time, the window at the edges begins to flicker, and the buttons in the non-client area seem to be in two positions at the same time. And if you pull the right edge, then the edge itself moves right behind the cursor (how to resize a folder in the view). I don't understand where the problem is, in calculating the new width of the window or position, or in general elsewhere in the code.
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{
    if (dragging) 
    {
        POINT currentPoint = { GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };
        GetCursorPos(&currentPoint);
        ScreenToClient(hwnd, &currentPoint);

        // Offset for THE RIGHT SIDE OF THE WINDOW
        int deltaXRight = currentPoint.x - startPoint.x;
        // New width OF THE RIGHT SIDE OF THE WINDOW
        int newWidth = startRect.right - startRect.left + deltaXRight;

        // Maybe I'm not doing the calculation correctly
        // Offset for the left SIDE of the WINDOW
        int deltaXLeft = startPoint.x - currentPoint.x;
        // New width OF THE LEFT SIDE OF THE WINDOW
        int newWidthLeft = startRect.right - startRect.left - deltaXRight;
        // New position of the left side
        int newCurrentWidthLeft = startRect.left + deltaXRight;

        if (startPoint.x > startRect.right - startRect.left - BORDERWIDTH)
        {
            SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, 0, 0, newWidth, startRect.bottom - startRect.top, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE);
        }
        else if (startPoint.x < BORDERWIDTH && newWidthLeft > MIN_WIDTH)
        {
            SetWindowPos(hwnd, NULL, newCurrentWidthLeft, startRect.top, newWidthLeft, startRect.bottom - startRect.top, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
        }
    }
    break;
}

The rest of the code
case WM_NCHITTEST: 
{
    POINT pt = { GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };
    ScreenToClient(hwnd, &pt);

    RECT closeButton = GetCloseButtonRect(hwnd);
    RECT maximizeButton = GetMaximizeButtonRect(hwnd);
    RECT minimizeButton = GetMinimizeButtonRect(hwnd);

    if (PtInRect(&closeButton, pt)) {
        return HTCLOSE;
    }
    else if (PtInRect(&maximizeButton, pt)) {
        return HTMAXBUTTON;
    }
    else if (PtInRect(&minimizeButton, pt)) {
        return HTMINBUTTON;
    }
    // Если курсор в заголовке, возвращаем HTCAPTION
    if (pt.y < GetTitleBarHeight()) {
        return HTCAPTION; // Указываем, что курсор в заголовке
    }

    LRESULT hit = DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    if (hit == HTCLIENT) {

        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
        if (pt.x > rc.right - 10) {
            return HTRIGHT; // Правый край
        }
        else if (pt.x < 10) {
            return HTLEFT; // Левый край
        }
    }
    return hit;
}
case WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN:
{ 
    POINT pt = { GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam) };
    ScreenToClient(hwnd, &pt);

    RECT closeButton = GetCloseButtonRect(hwnd);
    RECT maximizeButton = GetMaximizeButtonRect(hwnd);
    RECT minimizeButton = GetMinimizeButtonRect(hwnd);

    if (PtInRect(&closeButton, pt)) {
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
    }
    if (PtInRect(&maximizeButton, pt)) {
        ShowWindow(hwnd, IsZoomed(hwnd) ? SW_RESTORE : SW_MAXIMIZE);
    }
    if (PtInRect(&minimizeButton, pt)) {
        SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MINIMIZE, 0);
    }
    if (pt.y < GetTitleBarHeight()) {
        // Начинаем перетаскивание окна
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MOVE | HTCAPTION, lParam);
        return HTCAPTION;
    }
    dragging = true;
    startPoint.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
    startPoint.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &startRect);
    ScreenToClient(hwnd, &startPoint);
    
    SetCapture(hwnd); // Захватываем мышь

    return 0;
}

case WM_LBUTTONUP: {
    // Остановка изменения размера окна при отпускании левой кнопки мыши
    if (dragging) {
        dragging = false;
        ReleaseCapture(); // Освобождаем мышь
    }
    break;
}



Moving a window while it has capture is extra tricky. Instead, use WM_NCHITTEST and return HTLEFT or HTRIGHT. You can also use WM_SIZING to customize further.
